# cURL session authentication - working in OSX but not in Windows

Tags: php, windows, macos, session, curl

I am a noob on cURL - I am trying to authenticate a session with a server according to the documentation provided to me.

When I try the below command from OSX it works fine and I end up getting a "Session Successfully Authenticated" message.

But, when I try the exact same command from Windows (tried on 3 diff machines) It gives me "Authentication failed!" message.

```
curl --request POST http://xx.yy.zz.nnn/login.php --data 'username=ams' --data 'password=<password>' -c cookie.txt -v
```

In the verbose, the only difference I see between the two systems are - the content-length = 34 (in windows) and content-length = 30 (in OSX).

When I do a cURL from windows, is there any special consideration that needs to be taken into account when sending data??

Any help/pointer to resolve this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think osX using `utf-8` charset but windows `cp-1251`

Comment: I see the below on verbose in both cases.

`Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

I also see the curl version is diff in both -osx has 7.43.0 and windows has 7.49.1 - not sure if that will be the cause